# Reference a cross-object relationship or formula field using $ObjectType field set notation

Tags: validation-rule, cross-object

Is there a way to harness cross-object notation in conjunction with $ObjectType field set notation?

For example would it be possible to do the following: $ObjectType.**ChildObject__c**.Fields.**ParentObject__r**.**SomeField__c**

If this is not possible can $ObjectType field set notation reference a formula field:
$ObjectType.**ChildObject__c**.Fields.**FormulaField__c**

I'm getting the following error: 
Error: Field **ChildObject__c**.Fields.**FormulaField__c** does not exist. Check spelling.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_objecttype.htm